# What do glOrtho Parameters Correspond To?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, orthographic

I recently started using LWJGL and noticed that the `glOrtho` method takes the parameters left, right, bottom, top and cannot figure out what these correspond to.

I was confused when I noticed that

```
glOrtho(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1);
```

was the same as

```
glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1);
```

Am I correct in saying these to snippets of code are the same and if so why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are not the same:

```
glOrtho(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1);
```

will just generate a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error, and the commend has no further effect. The error occurs when left==right or top==bottom or near==far. (If it did not check for that condition, a division by zero would occur).

```
glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1);
```

is effectively doing nothing, as it will multiply the current matrix by an identity matrix.

It might appear as if those commands have the same result, but what actually happens is quite different.

Answer (score 4):

An orthographic projection is a rectangular parallelepiped (aka a box). The parameters for the `glOrtho` call define the clipping planes, or edges, of this box. Anything that lies outside of the projection box will not be rendered.

In regards to your example calls, the first one (`glOrtho(1,1,1,1,1,-1)`) is invalid and generates an `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`). Why? An orthographic projection is defined as

[image]

Notice the division by 0 errors due to `right == left` and `top == bottom`.

The second example (`glOrtho(-1,1,-1,1,1,-1)`)  simply creates an [identity matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix).

[Chapter 3 - OpenGL Programming Guide - Projection Transforms](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html#name3)

[ScratchPixel - Orthographic Projection Tutorial](http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-advanced-lessons/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/orthographic-projection/)